# smtplib email formatting

Tags: python

I am using smtplib to send emails with python. I can get the email to send with the info I want in the body, but I can't find a good source to look over on how I can format the mail itself.

Anyone know of a good resource....

I have a list that I want to iterate over and put lines between.

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you post an example of what your email would look like (a screenshot or just text is fine)?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an email question then a python question.  I'd refer to the RFC on email.  However to address your question in between lines of the body you should put a CRLF

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same stuff, so i will just share it with you.
Note : You can only do simple formatting (like simple tables, bold text)

Example is given below :

```
log = open("xyz.txt","r")
lines = [line.strip() for line in log]
FROM = 'abc@abc.com'
TO = 'abc@abc.com'
SMTP_TO = ['abc@abc.com']
mail_sub = 'Test Mail'
message = """From: abc@abc.com>
To: abc@abc.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: """ + mail_sub + """

Hello,
<br></br>
<br><b>Your message from text file is given below</b></br>
"""+'\n'.join(lines)+"""
<br><b>Thank you.</b></br>
"""
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('adress','port')
smtpObj.sendmail('%s'%FROM,SMTP_TO,message)
```

Above code reads data from `xyz.txt` file and embed it in the email using `'\n'.join(lines)`

Hope it helps you, Thanks.